# Change menubar items based on current NSViewController

Tags: cocoa, menuitem, nsviewcontroller

I have NSViewControllers for things like Orders and Clients.  These all live inside a tab view controller.  When I'm on the Orders, tab, I want the File->New to say New Order, and likewise New Client on that controller.

If I implement validateMenuItem: and change the name it's not just for that controller.  This means that every single view controller I create would have to reset the name back to just New.

How do I change titles of a menu item dynamically, based on the currently selected NSViewController?